# How to access Windows 10 PC from Ubuntu 14.04 using Remote Acess Client like Remmina

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04LTS and my friend has Laptop with Windows 10. How should I configure both these laptop so that I can access Windows desktop from my Ubuntu? Specifically how should I configure Windows so that it can be accessible from Ubuntu and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

I also was initially unable to connect to Windows 10 from Linux, but found a change to the Windows configuration and a reboot fixed it. There are actually several potential clients. You'll probably like remmina since it's friendly and GUI based, but I prefer the scripting friendly command line based xfreerdp because I can set it to reconnect as I prefer and include my credentials. Here's the command I use:

```
xfreerdp /u:'myusername@mydomain.com' /p:'mypassword' /sound:sys:alsa /size:1900x1050 /cert-ignore ignore certificate /v:192.168.0.1
```

See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287213

With reference to: https://cyberarms.net/security-insig...e-desktop.aspx

I changed the registry key

```
\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp SecurityLayer
```

from DWORD Hex '2' to a value of '1'

This reduces the security resilience of the windows machine but allows older software to remote in.

Comment: Do you need Windows 10 PRO for this to work?

Comment: Use https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/ if you are running Home edition - or want multiple connections to a Pro edition

Answer (score 1):

You can use Remote Desktop connection which is a feature in windows 10 and will let you connect to a computer which is on the same Network as yours, if you want to access his computer through the internet you would need to set up a VPN. You can also use a software like Hamachi to simulate a virtual network between you and your friend which is a very easy to configure and use.

To connect to the Windows machine you can use remmina. To connect from your windows machine to the Ubuntu machine you can use SSH or if you want a Graphical interface, VNC can be used.

You would first need to Enable Windows Remote desktop on the windows 10 PC. If you're on the same network as the PC, open remmina and choose the RDP protocol. Input the WIndows 10 IP and you should be able to connect. If you're trying this over the internet then you would need to setup a VPN like i said previously, which can be easily done with Hamachi.

Comment: Can you elaborate the procedure? Because I tried with remmina but enable to connect to windows 10 PC

Comment: Added explanations, guides to setting up Hamachi and VPNs are all over the internet. Also, be sure to use the RDP protocol in Remmina.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by installing [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) on the Windows computer and connecting with `remmina`.  You must open a port in the router to allow incoming connections to tightVNC.  The particulars are spelled out in the tightVNC documentation, not elaborating here since it's Windows.

You can then connect through `remmina` using the VNC protocol.

I cannot answer the Windows->Linux part of the question.  Although I could speculate that if you run `vino` on your Linux machine and open the appropriate port, your friend could connect with tightVNC.

Comment: Note that this will reuse the existing screen and not create a new session (login).